# How can i fix Index Out Of Range Exception of a char?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First the project it self i didn't do it i took it from github:

[spazzarama/Direct3DHook](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook)

The problem the exception happen when i try to use any directx11 game.
The exception happen in the DXHookD3D11.cs

```
#region Draw overlay (after screenshot so we don't capture overlay as well)
                if (this.Config.ShowOverlay)
                {
                    // Initialise Overlay Engine
                    if (_swapChainPointer != swapChain.NativePointer || _overlayEngine == null)
                    {
                        if (_overlayEngine != null)
                            _overlayEngine.Dispose();

                        _overlayEngine = new DX11.DXOverlayEngine();
                        _overlayEngine.Overlays.Add(new Capture.Hook.Common.Overlay
                        {
                            Elements =
                            {
                                //new Capture.Hook.Common.TextElement(new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 22)) { Text = "Test", Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 200), Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, AntiAliased = false},
                                new Capture.Hook.Common.FramesPerSecond(new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16)) { Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5,5), Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red, AntiAliased = true }
                            }
                        });
                        _overlayEngine.Initialise(swapChain);

                        _swapChainPointer = swapChain.NativePointer;
                    }
                    // Draw Overlay(s)
                    else if (_overlayEngine != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var overlay in _overlayEngine.Overlays)
                            overlay.Frame();
                        _overlayEngine.Draw();
                    }
                }
                #endregion
```

Then when it's trying to Draw() i used a breakpoint it's going to the class DXOverlayEngine.cs to this line:

```
_spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X, textElement.Location.Y, textElement.Text, textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
```

Then it's going to the DXSprite.cs to this part:

```
public void DrawString(int X, int Y, string text, int R, int G, int B, int A, DXFont F)
        {
            Color4 blendFactor = new Color4(1.0f);
            Color4 backupBlendFactor;
            int backupMask;
            var backupBlendState = _deviceContext.OutputMerger.GetBlendState(out backupBlendFactor, out backupMask);
            _deviceContext.OutputMerger.SetBlendState(_transparentBS, blendFactor);

            BeginBatch(F.GetFontSheetSRV());


            int length = text.Length;

            int posX = X;
            int posY = Y;

            Color4 color;
            Vector4 Vec = new Vector4(R > 0 ? (float)(R / 255.0f) : 0.0f, G > 0 ? (float)(G / 255.0f) : 0.0f, B > 0 ? (float)(B / 255.0f) : 0.0f, A > 0 ? (float)(A / 255.0f) : 0.0f);
            color = new Color4(Vec);

            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                char character = text[i];

                if (character == ' ')
                    posX += F.GetSpaceWidth();
                else if (character == '\n')
                {
                    posX = X;
                    posY += F.GetCharHeight();
                }
                else
                {
                    Rectangle charRect = F.GetCharRect(character);
```

And last it's doing the line F.GetCharRect(character) in the DXFont.cs class:

```
public Rectangle GetCharRect(char c)
        {
            Debug.Assert(_initialized);

            return _charRects[c - StartChar];
        }
```

I used a breakpoint on the method GetCharRect and for example in this case the variable c value is: 163'£ and the value in the variable StartChar is 33 '!'

Then it's showing the exception on the line:

```
return _charRects[c - StartChar];
```

I tried to ask the owner about this problem and so far all he told me is:

"Sounds like it is trying to draw a character that it hasn't prepared..."

I tried to narrow the code here as much as i can but it's all connect each other.

Comment: What's the size of the `_charRects` when you try to access it? In your example, you're accessing element 163-33 = 130. So if `_charRects` contains less than 131 elements, you're get the exception you're reporting.

Comment: Adding this to the GetCharRect method made it work: var index = c - StartChar;
if (index < 0 || index >= _charRects.Length) but this is not a solution for the problem it's just like a bypass. I mean now it seems to be working but i didn't trace and fixed the source of the problem.  Not sure if i know how to do it.

Comment: David for your question when the exception happen _charRects contain 94 elements.

Comment: All the code you have posted is irrelevant, only GetCharRect() and the missing creation of _charRects matter.

Comment: There's your problem then. As James Barrass' answer shows, you are creating two small an array and then reading beyond the end of it and so getting an out of bounds error.

Answer (score 2):

Looking in DXFont.cs it looks like it only prepares the characters with ASCII Codes between 33 and 127

```
     const char StartChar = (char)33; 
     const char EndChar = (char)127; 
     const uint NumChars = EndChar - StartChar;
```

The `_charRects` are set up during `BuildFontSheetBitmap` based on this range. You need to expand the range to include all the characters you want to render

Comment: Then why not changing it from 0 to 127 so the StartChar will be (char)0 ? I mean is it logic to include all the chars ? I mean why the owner set the range from 33 to 127 ?

Comment: @DanielHamutel chars that low are general not printable. Space is 32 and it's intentionally not included in the DrawString method, same with new line (13). I'd just increase the EndChar to include the characters you need to draw.